# How to find focus correctly with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a little search box like http://www.chess24.com/ up right of the page.

This is my peace of HTML:

```
<div class="input-group" id="searchBox">
    <input name="data[Search]" class="form-control" id="searchText" style="display : none; width : 0;" type="text"/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchBtn">Go!</button>
</div>
```

and the Jquery code is:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#searchBtn').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('#searchText').show();
        $('#searchText').animate({width: '200px'}, 500, function() {$('#searchText').focus();
        });
    });
    $('#searchText').blur(function() {
        if (!($('#searchBtn').is(":active")) && !($('#searchText').is(":active")) )
            $('#searchText').animate({width: '0'}, 500, function() {$(this).hide();});
        console.log($(document.activeElement));
    });


});
```

The problem is when focus going to button or click the button the TextBox will close.
i want to it close when point out of this two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
   var idx = event.target.id;
   //if clicked element is not searchText or searchbtn, but searchtext is visible
   if (idx !== 'searchText' && idx !== 'searchBtn' && $('#searchText').is(":visible")){
     $('#searchText').animate({width: '0'}, 500, function() {$(this).hide();});
   }
});
```

There are several ways to solve this. Just a hint.

Comment: Just instead of event should be e.target

Comment: And `event.target.id`, jQuery just makes the process a little more expensive at that point.